# Grub2 not showing Windows after dual boot with Arch

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, arch-linux, grub2

I have recently installed Arch Linux from Architect and came into a problem after install where Windows 10 does not show up on the grub2 menu. The only options that show up are Arch Linux and more options for Arch Linux. I have tried many things such as using os-prober and multiple ways of adding Windows to the grub menu but none of them worked. I can still access my Windows partition with Arch and it still has on my files in it. I need help with booting into Windows again.

Comment: [Here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) may be some useful tools to help you out.

Comment: Rescutux may help

Comment: Have you deleted any partition (e.g. System Reserved) before the installation?

Comment: I only deleted my old Ubuntu partition and overwrote a 500mb partition of what I think was a UEFI partition

Comment: I have decided to just reinstall the Windows boot manager and fix it from there

Comment: Rescutux did not work but super grub disk helped be get into Windows but I got an error. 0xc000000e